# Why does this golang program hang in playground when using for loop with select?

Tags: go

Consider this [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/tBfQL0MLnR)

```
    messages := make(chan int, 1)
    done := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        for {
        select {
            case msg := <- messages:
                fmt.Println("receiver one", msg)
            case signal := <-done :
                fmt.Println(signal)
                return
            default:
                fmt.Println("no message received")
        } 
        }
    }()
    go func() {
        for {
        select {
            case msg := <- messages:
                fmt.Println("receiver two", msg)
            case signal := <-done :
                fmt.Println(signal)
                return
            default:
                fmt.Println("no message received")
        } 
        }
    }()
    go func() {
       for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
           messages<-i
       }
       done<-true
       done<-true
       done<-true
    }()

    <-done
```

I am trying to simulate communicate from one thread to two other thread, but it seems like the above code is running fine in my local but not in playground.

Is there a trick to make the program work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the `default` clauses from the `select` statements.

Since your `select` statement is within a `for` loop and the `default` clause prevents it from blocking, the loop has to go through a lot of cycles before any message will be received.

Looks like Playground detects it and stops the program.

Comment: I think the default will run a couple times before the actual message is received, but since it is wrap in a for loop this means that eventually the receive case should be triggered?

Comment: That's right. But it seems that Playground enforces timeouts on goroutines. Here's what the about page states: `There are also limits on execution time and on CPU and memory usage`

Answer (score 1):

As @dev.bmax already mentioned, you use `default` in a wrong way.
Check this small [article](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/6) about using `default` keyword.

Also, try to add `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(4)` on the beginning of your program, run few times and check output to see, how it's working:

https://play.golang.org/p/TLDHNg6urB

Here's correct example for you:

https://play.golang.org/p/bc0TGdmx1Y

Note, that in this case you should use different channels for stopping additional and main goroutines.